# Let $H=\{2^m: m ∈ Z\}$ Where $m$ is any integer, and $ a\sim b\Leftrightarrow a/b $ is an element of $H$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Show that is an equivalence relation and describe the elements in the equivalence  class $\operatorname{cl}(3)$.

We're studying sets and equivalence in my mathematical proofs class. As this is a proofs class I require standard proof procedure in all my answers. Don't really know how to begin this one. Help please.

Comment: As equivalence relation $\sim$ must be defined on a set. What set do $a$ and $b$ belong to?

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, you need to show that the three properties are verified: reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

Before that, note that this is an equivalence on $\mathbb{R}^*$, i.e. the set of nonzero real numbers. The definition doesn't work for $b=0$. The domain of the relation should really have been given in the problem statement. (You can pick other domains, as long as they don't contain 0. Follow-up exercises: 1. what subsets of the reals can be the domain of this relation? 2. How can you extend the definition to cope with $b=0$ so that the resulting relation is an equivalence?)

The statement of reflexivity is: for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$, $a/a \in H$. Given $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$, we have $a/a = 1 = 2^0 \in H$. This proves reflexivity.

I leave the proof of symmetry and transitivity to you. They can work along similar lines.

The definition of $\mathrm{cl}(3)$ is that it's the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^*$ such that $x \sim 3$ (or the set such that $3 \sim x$, it's the same set by symmetry). That is:
$$ \begin{align*}
  \mathrm{cl}(3) &
  = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^* : x/3 \in H \}
  = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^* : \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}, x/3 = 2^m \} \\
  &= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^* : \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}, x = 3 \cdot 2^m \}
  = \{ 3 \cdot 2^m : m \in \mathbb{Z} \}
\end{align*} $$